# Cannot create ASP.NET MVC projects in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web but I am unable to create any ASP.NET MVC projects, as there are no ASP.NET project options. Is there a separate download or something?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC isn't included in Visual Studio. You can install it as extension to VS. It is that way because it's being updated more frequently than VS itself, also it's open source.

Comment: What if you select `C#` then `Web`? I think that's the correct order, but I'm not on my work system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try downloading/installing:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

edit: I'm not referring to downloading Visual Studio. The link I posted is specifically for installing MVC 4 that isn't included in Visual Studio by default. Is it this ASP.NET MVC Extension that you've downloaded? ALSO.. to create an ASP.NET MVC site you have to select NEW->Project and then click on Web sub-category under a language of your choice , not new->Web Site.

Comment: I installed it but I still cannot create any ASP.NET projects.

Answer (score 0):

Change .net framework version to 4.5